# Is there any way to specify an offset for a cell in a named range within a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Suppose I've created these named ranges: Apples = "A1:A3", Pears = "B1:B3"

Then putting the formula "=Apples + Pears" in cell C3 is the same as "=A3 + B3"

Is there some way to specify an offset in the "=Apples + Pears" formula so that cell C3 refers to "=A3 + B2" instead?

In other words, how would an offset for "Pears" be specified so that it refers to B2 instead of B3?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: I would like the formula to be relative, so that if I copied it to cell C2 it would refer to "=A3 + B1"

Comment: So, below answer solves your problem or still need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ROW() function of the current cell to get an index that is automatically updated when you copy the formula. This formula goes into C3, then when you drag it up, it automatically adjusts the index for Pears.

```
=INDEX(Apples,3,1)+INDEX(Pears,ROW(C3)-1,1)
```

Note that if your real data doesn't start in row 2, you'll need to subtract the additional amount from the row function to allow for the additional rows.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The **OFFSET function** will do the trick to move from cell B3 one cell up:

For numbers use the following function (e.g. number 3):

> =A3+OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(3,B:B,0),2)),-1,0)

And for strings use this function:

> =A3&OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Pears",B:B,0),2)),-1,0)

Comment: Thanks, that works for specific cells.  But what would be the syntax for using OFFSET with a named range?  For example, =OFFSET (Pears,0,0) gives a "#VALUE!" error ("A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type.").

Comment: @Dionysus17 see if the updated formula above is what you are after.

Comment: Updated my formula. You can't put numbers in quotation marks.

Comment: If Pears = "B1:B3" wont work, because you can set and IF statement equal to a cell unless you build it into an array formula.

Comment: Does your 1st formula assume that "3" is in cell B3?  That formula works, but I was looking for a general way to reference B2 relative to B3, rather than searching for particular value and offsetting from that (I edited my original question to clarify that).

Comment: The 2nd formula gives a #REF! error (invalid cell reference), if I include the word "Pears" in the cell B1 (the range "Pears" = "B2:B4").  If Pears = "B1:B3" then "MATCH("Pears",B:B,0)" gives a #N/A error (value not available).  Am I misinterpreting what you wrote?

Comment: "If Pears = "B1:B3" wont work, because you can set and IF statement equal to a cell unless you build it into an array formula."      Can you clarify what that comment is referring to?

Comment: An IF statement can only equal to one cell. But in the function above you are not using an IF statement, so you should be in the clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The info about these functions is very helpful.

Comment: @Dionysus17 No worries, glad somebody was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to specify a cell within a range, named or conventional.

```
=index(apples, 3, 1) + index(pears, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want for cell C3.   However, I would like to copy and paste that formula into cell C2 and get this:   =index(apples, 3, 1) + index(pears, 1, 1).  Is there any way to do that without using an additional column which contains the row index for pears -- i.e., by creating a relative formula like this: =index(apples, 3, 1) + index(pears, D2, 1), where  D1:D3 = (0,1,2) ?

Comment: Looks like the formula you provided in your comment would work. e.g. `=index(apples, 3, 1) + index(pears, D2, 1)` where D1:D3 = (0,1,2). It just wouldn't work in C1 (there is no row zero).

Comment: Thanks for your help. BTW -- Michael's solution eliminates the column for the row index.